# How to create Indonesian environmental conditions in India?

Tags: meteorology, environmental-protection, regional-geology, environmental-sensors

Need to create and maintain Biofloc for fish farming in India, it's really successful in Indonesia and I believe it's due to environmental conditions.

Can we replicate the same in India?

Comment: Biofloc appears to be another form of fish/marine farming. Instead of trying to farm the species farmed in Indonesia find a species that will be appropriate for conditions in India, & one for which there will be a market. The main environmental factors to consider are to ensure the farms are established in clean areas & that they do not themselves pollute the marine environment.

Comment: We are trying Indian species only. However maintaining microbes is a challenge (BioFloc)